# How do I call scrapy from airflow dag?

Tags: scrapy, airflow

My scrapy project runs perfectly well with 'scrapy crawl spider_1' command. How to trigger it (or call the scrappy command) from airflow dag?

```
with DAG(<args>) as dag:
     scrapy_task = PythonOperator(
          task_id='scrapy',
          python_callable= ?)
     task_2 = ()
     task_3 = ()
   ....
scrapy_task >> [task_2, task_3, ...]
```

Comment: Use BashOperator

Answer (score 4):

#### Run with BashOperator

- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html

```py
with DAG(<args>) as dag:
     scrapy_task = BashOperator(
          task_id='scrapy',
          bash_command='scrapy crawl spider_1')
```

- If you're using virtualenv, you may use [VirtualEnvOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/python.html#pythonvirtualenvoperator)

  - or to use existing environment, you can use `source activate venv && scrapy crawl spider_1`

#### Run with PythonOperator

- From scrapy documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

```py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl('spider_1')
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Comment: Thank you. One problem I'm facing now is that although the crawling works, the extracted data doesn't get saved in database. Any idea why or any solutions for the same?

Comment: @Rabindra In a nutshell you have to create a class that handle this "insert". Take a look on this two examples: [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb), [medium](https://medium.com/codelog/store-scrapy-crawled-data-in-postgressql-2da9e62ae272)